# sympy compiling functions with large matrices

Tags: python, c, cython, sympy

I have been using `sympy` to work with systems of differential equations. I write the equations symbolically, use `autowrap` to compile them through cython, and then pass the resulting function to the scipy ODE solver. One of the major benefits of doing this is that I can solve for the jacobian symbolically using the sympy `jacobian` function, compile it, and it to the ODE solver as well.

This has been working great for systems of about 30 variables. Recently I tried doing it with 150 variables, and what happened was that I ran out of memory when compiling the jacobian function. This is on Windows with anaconda and the microsoft Visual C++ 14 tools for python. Basically during compilation of the jacobian, which is now a 22000-element vector, memory usage during the linking step went up to about 7GB (on my 8GB laptop) before finally crashing out.

Does someone have some suggestions before I go and try on a machine with more memory? Are other operating systems or other C compilers likely to improve the situation?

I know lots of people do this type of work, so if there's an answer, it will be beneficial to a good chunk of the community.

> Edit: response to some of Jonathan's comments:

Yes, I'm fully aware that this is an N^2 problem. The jacobian is a matrix of all partial derivatives, so it will have size N^2. There is no real way around this scaling. However, a 22000-element array is not nearly at the level that would create a memory problem during runtime -- I only have the problem during compilation.

Basically there are three levels that we can address this at.

1) solve the ODE problem without the jacobian, or somehow split up the jacobian to not have a 150x150 matrix. That would address the very root, but it certainly limits what I can do, and I'm not yet convinced that it's impossible to compile the jacobian function

2) change something about the way `sympy` automatically generates C code, to split it up into multiple chunks, use more functions for intermediate expressions, to somehow make the .c file smaller. People with more sympy experience might have some ideas on this.

3) change something about the way the C is compiled, so that less memory is needed.

I thought that by posting a separate question more oriented around #3 ([literal referencing of large array -- compiler out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380587/literal-referencing-of-large-array-compiler-out-of-memory)) , I would get a different audience answering. That is in fact exactly what happened. Perhaps the answer to #3 is "you can't" but that's also useful information.

Comment: I have to second this question, as I'm bound by the same limitation; however, for me, I get the message "fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2", rather than a straight up crash. Quick attempts on ubuntu + gcc-compiler on a colleague's machine did not solve the problem unfortunately. If nothing else helps, one can work around this dirtily by using 'autowrap' on a few submatrices of the Jacobian, and define a function in python to put the parts together again. That's of course a workaround and far from ideal.

Comment: Yes, sorry I used "crash" somewhat loosely. I get either the same or a similar error.

Comment: Note the follow-on question [Literal referencing of large array — compiler out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380587).  That is currently closed as a duplicate of this.  Please flag this comment 'no longer needed' if the duplicate status is changed.

Comment: As noted in the other question, your problem seems to be scaling O(N²).  You will rapidly run out of memory, regardless of how much you have, as your problem size grows.  You need to work out a way to avoid the quadratic growth of your solution code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a lot of the examples posted at http://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/ I was able to get this to compile.

The key things were
1) instead of using `autowrap`, write the C code directly with more control over it. Among other things, this allows passing the argument list as a vector instead of expanding it. This took some effort to get working (setting up the compiler flags through distutils, etc, etc) but in the end it worked well. Having the repo from the course linked above as an example helped a lot.

2) using common subexpression elimination (`sympy.cse`) to dramatically reduce the size of the expressions for the jacobian elements.

(1) by itself didn't do that much to help in this case (although I was able to use it to vastly improve performance of smaller models). The code was still 200 MB instead of the original 300 MB. But combining it with (2) (`cse`) I was able to get it down to a meager 1.7 MB (despite 14000 temporary variables).

The `cse` takes about 20-30 minutes on my laptop. After that, it compiles quickly.